# How do I give Outlook folder permissions to a user not in GAL?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange-2007

I need to share an *Exchange 2007* email folder with a particular user.  In *Outlook 2007*, I right-click the folder and go to **Properties, Permissions**.  I press **Add** which brings up the Global Address List.  However, the user I need to add is not in the GAL because at a business level it is a "robot" user, not a real person.

Ultimately, the user requires permission to view messages, and modify the read status and categories of each message.  Being a delegate of the mailbox is not sufficient.

How can I give email folder permissions to a user not listed in the GAL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Outlook, the users must be visible in the GAL to provide permissions, even if you type in the name or the email address of the person you wish to provide permissions.

Although, from the server side, permissions can be provided using PFDAVADMIN. It is a GUI that allow you to change or set permissions on mailboxes or Public Folders.

Details are here: http://www.msdigest.net/2008/07/pfdavadmin-and-exchange-2007/